# need to access the file "etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml" on node? #istio

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, openshift, istio

Istio installation using docs “https://istio.io/docs/setup/platform-setup/openshift/“.
How we can do WebhookAdmission in open shift cluster 4.1 on aws. file (etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml) should be present on master instance but its not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenShift 4.1 is based on Kubernetes 1.13, and [MutatingAdmissionWebhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#mutatingadmissionwebhook) is enabled by default in Kubernetes 1.13. See here [UPDATING THE MASTER CONFIGURATION](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/servicemesh-install/servicemesh-install.html#updating-master-configuration)
, `Master configuration updates are not necessary if you are running OpenShift Container Platform 4.1.` as mentioned.